# simplify equation by removing double summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Is it possible to simplify the following function by removing the double summation?

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{x-1} \sum_{m=n+1}^x a_{n}b_{m}$$

Or is there no way of removing the sigmas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you can do, but if you like you could write

\begin{align}
f(x)
&=
\sum_{n=1}^{x-1}\sum_{m=n+1}^xa_nb_m
\\
&=
\sum_{n=1}^{x-1}\sum_{m=n}^{x-1}a_nb_{m+1}
\\
&=
\sum_{{\scriptstyle m,n=1}\atop{\scriptstyle m\ge n}}^{x-1}a_nb_{m+1}
\end{align}